# How do I set transaction priority with the JSON RPC wallet?

Tags: transaction-fees, monero-wallet-rpc

I'm trying to find how to set the payment priority when making a transfer using the JSON RPC wallet, but can't find the parameter in the documentation, probably because it hasn't been updated since the last hardfork.

Can I simply use these parameters (https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/developer-guides/wallet-rpc#transfer) and add a "priority" parameter with a value between 1 and 4 (0 being the default anyway)?

I have read here (https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/65oqao/fees_barely_went_down_why/) that a default priority can be set in the CLI wallet, but I'm not sure this applies to the RPC wallet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfer_split RPC indeed has a priority field, which may be set to 0-4, as you suspected. 0 stands for default (which is 2 currently, but will use the default you set via simplewallet if any), and 1-4 for their respective priorities (unimportant, normal, medium, highest).

The documentation does indeed need updating, this is one of these neverending tasks that often get behind.

Comment: Oh wow... I feel like hiding in a wall. :-D Don't know why I wrote XML everywhere, but thanks for pointing it out. I updated my question.

Thanks for your help! Is there a way to list available parameters for each function? I mean, besides looking at the source code?

Comment: The documentation you looked at lists available parameters at the time it was written. If it was up to date, it would be that. Otherwise, it's the code (but it's pretty easy to understand code, as it just lists the fields: src/wallet/wallet_rpc_command_defs.h)

Comment: The documentation update was crowdfunded: https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/87101/update-getmonero-org-developer-documentation No idea the status. But not much incentive for others to work on it if someone else is being paid to do it...